# Regex to match words within a specified distance of one another without a period occurring between them

Tags: regex-lookarounds

I am working with some text and looking to match instances of phrases like "The Secretary shall determine..." I want to allow for a certain amount of space between "Secretary" and "determine" for the purpose of flexibility (sometimes there will be something like "The Secretary, in concurrence with the Administrator, shall determine"). I've been using this:

```
\\bSecretary\\W+(?:\\w+\\W+){1,16}?determine\\b
```

However, my issue is that this will sometimes pick up instances in which "Secretary" and "determine" are in separate sentences. How can I specify that I do not want to match a co-occurrence of these two words if there is a period anywhere between them? For example, I would not want to match "...selected by the Secretary. The Commissioner may determine..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the following negative look-ahead:

```
\bSecretary(?![.!?] )\W+(?:\w+(?![.!?] )\W+){1,16}?determine\b
```

I added two extra things:

1. Support for exclamation marks and question marks.
2. Requirement that the period is followed by a space (otherwise a dot not ending the sentence could be matched, e.g. inside `2.5%`).

You can test this [here](https://regex101.com/r/myuGkT/1).

Answer (score 0):

Use a character class for “non-word and non-dot” ie `[^\w.]` where you have used “non-word” `\W`:

```
\bSecretary[^\w.]+(?:\w+[^\w.]+){0,16}determine\b'
```

Notice also that you can replace `{1,16}?` with `{0,16}`.